# Laravel's deleteDirectory ignores preserve flag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-storage

Looking at Laravel's 5.7 [deleteDirectory](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_deleteDirectory) method in the API, it has a `preserve` flag to just empty the directory in each case.

I want 4 dirs to be emptied working with Laravel 5.7:

```
$dirs = ['dir1', 'dir2', 'dir3', 'dir4'];
foreach ($dirs as $dir)
    Storage::deleteDirectory($dir, true);
```

The code is executed, but it also removes the dirs themselves, which is not the desired behaviour.

Also, method [cleanDirectory](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_cleanDirectory) of the API results in a `Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::cleanDirectory` error...

Any ideas?

Comment: did you use `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem as Storage;`, because that's the API for the Filesystem class you linked, not this Storage class you are calling?

Comment: secondly, `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` does not appear to use the League's flysystem, but the call to that is deleteDir($dir), with no boolean second argument https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using Illuminate Filesystem, you are using the PHP League of Extraordinary Packages Flystem (which I absolutely love).

Here are the correct docs for the classes you are using.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#directories

https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/usage/filesystem-api/

It doesn't appear that there is a preserve option.